# A noncontinous algebra map between Banach algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

What is an example of two Banach algebras $A$ and $B$, and an algebra map $\phi:A \to B$ which is not continuous?

Comment: It is impossible to exhibit a discontinuous linear map between Banach spaces without the axiom of choice
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map

Comment: Asked and answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11537/is-there-an-algebraic-homomorphism-between-two-banach-algebras-which-is-not-cont/111630#111630). (The accepted answer is incorrect: it is the existence of discontinuous homomorphism *from $C(X)$* which is independent of ZFC. The second answer gives a trivial construction of a discontinuous homomorphism between Banach algebras.)

Comment: What about a noncontinuous algebra map between two topological algebras?

Comment: Take $B = l^1(\mathbb{Z})$, a Banach algebra with convolution product, and let $\phi: B \to C(\mathbb{T})$ be the Gelfand transform. It is 1-1 and nonexpansive onto its image but not onto $C(\mathbb{T})$. Letting $A = \phi(B)$, we get a discontinuous homomorphism $\phi^{-1}: A \to B$.